# Can't pass search term as parameter

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I want to display some data in a dropdown and implement autocomplete. In order to do that I'm using `select2`, a jQuery plugin.
My problem is that the search term written in the search box is not being passed as parameter to my method in the controller . This is my ajax request:

```
$('#someId').select2({
        minimumInputLength: 1,
        allowClear: true,

        ajax: {
            url: "/controllerName/methodName",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "GET",
            data: function (params) {

                var queryParameters = {
                    term: params.term

                }
                return queryParameters;

            },

            processResults: function (data) {
                return {
                    results: $.map(data, function (students) {
                        return {
                            text: students.name,
                            id: students.id
                        }
                    })
                };
            }
        }
    });
```

And this is the html:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label asp-for="someId" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
 <div class="col-md-4">
<select asp-for="someId"  class="form-control" style="display:table-cell; 
 width:100%"></select>
 </div>
 </div>
```

This is my method in controller:

```
[HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetStudents(string searchTerm)
    {
        //some code
    }
```

Is there anything wrong in my Ajax request?

Comment: can we see the controller method please? Have you checked your browser's network tools to see if the value is sent correctly? (it will be in the request URL's querystring I think, since it's a GET request). That will tell you if it's a client-side or server-side issue, to start with.

Comment: @ADyson I checked the browser's network tools and the parameter is in the URL's query string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending a variable called "term" as your search parameter. But your controller is expecting a variable called "searchTerm".

The variable names need to match, otherwise how should the controller know what to pick out from the querystring?

Especially consider the very-common situation where there are multiple parameters being sent from the browser. At that point it's critical there is a naming convention so the correct parameters are matched to the correct variable in the controller method.